# Why aren't function reference in JSX "sugar"ified?

Tags: reactjs

For Example,

We could just use

```
onClick={(foo)}
```

or something else.. instead of

```
onClick={this.foo.bind(this)}
```

Just curious if there is any particular technical constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer the question from a design/philosophical perspective, instead of a technical one (the other answers do that pretty well already).

React COULD have, there would be no problem to that. But why have multiple ways to do things when you can have one (React tries to stay as close to ES standards as possible). If there are multiple ways to do a single task, it'll affect readability across codebases, making it harder for developers to ease into a codebase since they would have to unravel layers upon layers of abstraction till they gets to the core idea.

Basically, I think it was a design choice to NOT add a lot of the syntactic sugar that could have been added (JSX itself is already a form of syntactic sugar, we don't need syntactic sugar on our syntactic sugar).

From the React Docs:

*"In general we resist adding features that can be implemented in userland. We don't want to bloat your apps with useless library code. However, there are exceptions to this."*

*"We prefer boring code to clever code. Code is disposable and often changes. So it is important that it doesn't introduce new internal abstractions unless absolutely necessary."*

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/contributing/design-principles.html

Representing the ideas from this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4anAwXYqLG8

Answer (score 1):

1. `onClick={foo}` is something completely different to `onClick={this.foo.bind(this)}`, and parentheses are required for maths.
2. `.bind` causes a new function to be created on every single invocation, so this would not be very performant.
3. (I assume) an aim of JSX to try and be as close to regular JS as possible so it's easy to pick up.
4. It is not the realm of JSX to add new language elements; a bind operator is most definitely a new language element.

If you notice, JSX doesn't provide any new language constructs other than what is necessary to call `React.createElement`. Additionally, you probably wouldn't want to use `.bind` like this anyway due to fact it's creating a new function every time. Finally, the parens are required for mathematical operations - you couldn't use `{()}` because what if I wanted to use a mathematical operation like `{(a + b) * c}`? Any interpolation that JSX does must be a JavaScript expression, currently, so unless JavaScript itself supports this syntax it's unlikely the interpolation will too.

You may be interested in the [function bind](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/05/14/function-bind) operator, but I'd recommend you avoid using bind in this manner; instead, bind the functions once in the component constructor, like so:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.boundOnClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.boundOnClick}>Foo</button>
  }
}

// with function bind operator

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.boundOnClick = ::this.onClick
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.boundOnClick}>Foo</button>
  }
}
```

This ensures you only create the bound function once. For stateless components, you don't have access to `this` anyway so there's no need to use bind.

If JSX were to introduce an alternative syntax to this, I personally would be opposed to it, though if they could overcome the limitations I've mentioned above, there's nothing technically stopping them.

Answer (score 0):

It is more a problem with ES6 which does not have automatic binding of "this" to class methods. In ES7, there is a proposal to introduce a new operator ::. With ES7, you could write:

```
onClick={this::foo}
```

Comment: Note that `this::foo` can be shortened to `::foo`.